# How to use Facebook URL Schemes in IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, url-scheme, applinks

I have been trying to use the facebook URL Schemes on stackoverflow which reference to here http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook (and similar sites).

I am having trouble sending the app user to another user's profile in the facebook app. I have the other users screenName (and id, but prefer to use screenName).

I have tried

- `fb://profile/id`
- `fb://profile/screenname`
- `fb://profile?id=id`

I am unsure the difference here with `(initWithUID)` and `(fbid)` of these and similiar calls:

- `fb://profile/(initWithUID:)`
- `fb://profile/(initWithUID:)/addfriend`
- `fb://profile/(fbid)`
- `fb://profile/(fbid)/addfriend`

All of these seem not to open the user who owns the screenname/id profile view in the facebook app.

By screenname I mean that in a browser:

- `facebook.com/screenname` sends you to their profile page and
- `graph.facebook.com/screenname` gives you their id

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. For Android it is known to work, but it is not officially supported. For iOS it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the Facebook docs or another reputable source to back up your claim that "It's not possible?"

Comment: Yes; I work at Facebook :) And it's not documented since it's not supported; we don't document all the things that can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

I just succeeded in opening the profile in the Facebook app with:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/whitehouse")!)
```